# Eigenvalues properties under Cayley transform

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have some matrix $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and Cayley transform defined as
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{\mathbf{A}} = (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A})(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A})^{-1}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix.

1. Can we say something about how spectra $\sigma(\mathbf{A})$ and $\sigma(\tilde{\mathbf{A}})$ are related in terms of eigenvalues (some closed form formula for instance)?
2. Is it possible to convert from one to other by knowing its minors and determinant?

Comment: In general if $f(\cdot)$ is analytic then spectrum of $f(A)$ is $f(\lambda_i)$. See Spectral Mapping Theorem.